# Find all closed subsets of a given X

Tags: general-topology

Let $X$ = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5} and $\tau$ = {$\emptyset$, {1}, {1,2}, {1,2,5}, {1,3,4}, {1,2,3,4}, $X$}. Show that $\tau$ is a topology and find all closed subsets of $X$.

I showed that $\tau$ is a topology via the definition, but I'm not quite sure whether I have found the correct closed subsets. My suggestions would be:

open sets: bascially all of $\tau$, so: 
open sets = $\emptyset$, {1}, {1,2}, {1,2,5}, {1,3,4}, {1,2,3,4}, $X$

closed sets: I far I understand it, the closed sets are the complements of the members of $\tau$ (in regards to $X$), so: 
closed sets = $X$, {2,3,4,5}, {3,4,5}, {3,4}, {2,5}, {5}, $\emptyset$

Comment: What you have done is correct. Those are the closed sets of $X$

Comment: Perfect answer!